# Is the statement of Baker's Theorem on wikipedia inaccurate?

Tags: algebraic-numbers, transcendence-theory

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem) on Baker's theorem states it as follows:

> If $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{L}$ are linearly independent over the rational numbers, then for any algebraic numbers $\beta_0,\ldots,\beta_n$, not all zero we have
> $$|\beta_0+\beta_1\lambda_1+\cdots+\beta_n\lambda_n|>H^{-C}$$
> where $H$ is the maximum of the heights of $\beta_i$ and $C$ is an effectively computable number depending on $n$, $\lambda _{i}$ and the maximum $d$ of the degrees of $\beta_i$.

But I don't think this holds if the $\beta_i$ have height at most $1$. For example consider $|\log(2\cdot3)-\log(3)|=\log(2)<1$.
I'm assuming the height of an algebraic number $\beta$ refers to $\max_i(|a_i|)$ where the $a_i$ are the coefficients of an irreducible polynomial of $\beta$ such that the coefficients are relatively prime integers.
I've also checked Baker's book Transcendental Number Theory and in place of $H$ he uses $B\geq 2$, an upper-bound of $H$.

Comment: 1) Why would logarithms of integers be algebraic? 2) The height of an algebraic number $\alpha$ is $\prod_v{\max(|\alpha|_v,1)}$ where $v$ runs over all the places of a given number field containing $\alpha$, and $|\cdot|_v$ is the associated normalized absolute value.

Comment: @Aphelli for your point 1), OP is using $\log(6)$ and $\log(3)$ for the $\lambda_i$, not the $\beta_i$.

Comment: @BrunoB: I see, thank you for pointing out my mistake. Then I think that you’re right and the Wikipedia statement is indeed false – unless we take $H \geq 1+\epsilon$.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm using the definition of height as given in Baker's Transcendental Number Theory, chapter $3$ Lower bounds for Linear Forms, in the introduction.